# trying to understand some bits i found in Opencv & c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Hey peeps am studding opencv and running through some tutorials, i came across these attributes well I think they are that the problem really I dont know what they are tried google it but with no luck:

So these are the bits that i have no idea what they are have a look maybe someone can explain these to me so the tutorials will have more sense to me:

```
vector<Vec4i>() //I know what vector is :) but Vec4i....?
CV_8UC1 // <------- ?
```

Comment: Vec4i is a type, CV_8UC1 looks like a macro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenCV basic structures page (under the [`Vec` section](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#vec)) explains that `Vec4i` is a `typedef`, equivalent to `Vec<int, 4>`, a vector of 4 integers.

Additionally, on the same page (under the [`Mat` section](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat)), it explains that `CV_8UC1` is an 8-bit single-channel matrix. Specifically:

- `8` indicates the bit depth
- `U` indicates that it is `unsigned`
- `C1` indicates that there is a single channel.

[Here's](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00023000000000000000) a page with more information about OpenCV naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you so much great just wont i need to know and wonted

Comment: @Tomazi Just for future reference, what and wanted are spelt with an 'a' and not an 'o'. Also nice answer Walfie, +1

Comment: Hey again just one quick question C1 single channel means the stored image will be Grayscale or black an white where C3 would be used for color images...?#

Comment: @Tomazi Yes, single-channel matrices are suitable for storing greyscale images, and three-channel matrices for colored images (the three channels being red, green, and blue)

Answer (score 1):

1. `Vec4i` is just a `typedef` of a a vector:

   `typedef Vec<int, 4> Vec4i;` from [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html?highlight=vec4i).
2. `CV_8UC1` is a #Define which helps with initialization of OpenCV matrices:

   e.g.

   CV_8UC1 means 8-bit single-channel matrix,

If you ever need OpnenCV type advice look at the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html).

It is very helpful.